# Python custom functions not getting called in fission logs error 502 bad gateway

Tags: python, kubernetes-fission

I have installed fission and created

1. Package
2. Env
3. function hello world
4. tested and running fine

But
When i tried to run custom functions like finding a max number.

```
if x > y:
        return x
    return  #y
def max_of_three( x, y, z ):
    return max_of_two( x, max_of_two( y, z ) )
print(max_of_three(3, 6, -5))
```

it gives a error

`Error querying logs: Internal error - 502 Bad @Gateway%`

Also when i try to check logs the same error reflecting

Answer (score 0):

I have used custom functions in Python on Fission and they work fine. I followed [this blog post](https://fission.io/blog/single-or-monolith-serverless-functions-what-should-you-choose/) as is and it worked without any issue.

Also, have you checked the following:

1. Check if the package build of your function has succeeded with
   `fission pkg list`
2. Check if your route is correct with `fission route list`
3. Check the logs of your router pod to see if the request got
   through
4. Use `fission function test` with `--verbosity=2` to test your
   function locally, post your output here

I found these above steps mentioned for a similar error in their [slack channel](https://fissionio.slack.com/archives/C3LUX6BBP/p1611908818023300?thread_ts=1611840045.022600&cid=C3LUX6BBP).